# Input multiple tags into <ui tags drop> field

Tags: jquery, html, tags, formatting, user-input

I need to input  a large amount of keywords (6000) in "tag" field. For some reason the tags don't get inputed correctly if separated by comma, the only way is by entering them one by one entering "return" key after each one.

Do you know how i can input them in a easy/automated manner? I tried macros but not working properly...

I think it has to see with the "ui-tags-drop" field as all input gets written there and upon hitting return a new  is created and is also added into "ui-class-hidden". I am no technical user though,

Many thanks for your help! Here is the code of the field:

```
<div class="ui-tags" style="width: calc(100% - 289px);float: right;margin-right:-2px;">
<span class="tag" data-value="cumberlandhotellondon">cumberlandhotellondon<i></i></span>
<span class="tag" data-value="studios2let">studios2let<i></i></span>
<span class="tag" data-value="cromwellcrown">cromwellcrown<i></i></span>
<span class="tag" data-value="stgileshotel">stgileshotel<i></i></span>

<input class="ui-tags-input" type="text" style="width: 134.063px;">
<input class="ui-tags-hidden targeting-rule-value-sub-val" type="hidden" value="cumberlandhotellondon|studios2let|cromwellcrown|stgileshotel||>

<ul class="ui-tags-drop" style="display: none;">
<li data-value="" value="">&nbsp;</li></ul></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JUst found answer by coincidence, separate all keywords with "|" and it does the trick!